# How to Stop a CChildView Timer from Modeless Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a timer with `SetTimer( 1 , 25 , 0 );` during `CChildView::PreSubclassWindow()`.

In `CChildView::OnTimer()` I do `InvalidateRect(  0 , 0 );` to cause an `CChildView::OnPaint()`. This causes a record from a file to be read and painted.

All of this works just fine.

During `MyApp::InitInstance()` I created a modeless dialog with several controls that all work as expected.

What I want to do is control the timer running in `CChildView` from a dialog control.
The problem is, I can't find or have access to the instance of `CChildView`.
Hence I can't call my `SetTimerSpeed()` function in `CChildView`.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Use a custom windows message (user message) and post the time to be set to the window handle of the CChildView. Add a handler for the message to CChildView and set the timer speed. See [WM_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user) _"...Used to define private messages ..."_

Comment: Richard, Many thanks for post. have tried to #define custom msg but just get error when trying to create handler with Class wizard.  Had look on MS site for how to guide but no luck. I'll scratch about bit more but think time to junk MFC and redo the project in win32. thanks again

Comment: Richard, VS2022 Class Wizard  does not seem able to produce the msg handler etc. So as much use as a Rubber Beak on  a Woodpecker. Working now as used this guide
https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=00750-ee5dc960-ea95-4317-90ce-84c137a1b151
Thanks again imk

Answer (score 0):

When creating the dialog store a pointer to your view in the dialog object. You can just use this one to access the view instance. Add a view-pointer member in your dialog class declaration:

```
class CMyDialog : public CDialogEx
{
    public:
        CChildView *pView;
    .
    .
}
```

And when calling it:

```
CMyDialog ctDlg;
ctDlg.pView = this;
ctDlg.DoModal();
// or ctDlg.Create();
```

The code above of course can be called from a handler (function) in CChildView.

If the application is SDI you don't even need this, you can just store the pointer to the view in a global variable, it is very much OK:

```
// Declaration in the .h file
extern CChildView *pChldVw;

// Definition in the .cpp file
CChildView *pChldVw;

// CChildView constructor
CChildView::CChildView() noexcept
{
    pChldVw = this;
}
```

If the application is MDI and the dialog is not created in the `CChildView` code, it is still possible to find the view instance by calling something like:

```
CMDIFrameWnd *pFrame = (CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();

// Get the active MDI child window.
CMDIChildWnd *pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)pFrame->GetActiveFrame();

// Get the active view attached to the active MDI child window.
CChildView *pView = (CChildView)pChild->GetActiveView();
```

There are also some "enumeration" functions, like:

- `GetFirstDocTemplatePosition()` / `GetNextDocTemplate()`
- `GetFirstDocPosition()` / `GetNextDoc()`
- `GetFirstViewPosition()` / `GetNextView()`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, now sorted :-)